# Calling a CPLEX (.mod) file which is linked with Excel

Tags: python, cplex

I want to call a .mod CPLEX file from Python. In the next link, there are instructions on how to call CPLEX within Python:

[How to run a .mod file (CPLEX) using python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60598747/how-to-run-a-mod-file-cplex-using-python)

[Code](https://github.com/AlexFleischerParis/zoodocplex/blob/master/zoocallopl.py)

But, in my case, the .mod file uses data read from Excel. In this case, do I need to use:

```
import pandas
```

Is it a correct or good approach to do something like this (calling a CPLEX (.mod) file which is linked with Excel)?

In the links, *buses* are defined as a *bus* structure that has *nbSeats* and *cost* features.

But what if there is no such structure in the problem, and there are only separate variables and parameters, then what should we use instead of `opl.set_input()`?

For example, if there are only variables or parameters like *nbKids* defined in the codes, how we can pass it from Python to a CPLEX .mod file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

as you can see in https://github.com/AlexFleischerParis/zoodocplex/blob/master/zoocalloplwithdataindatfile.py

```
you can use a .dat file with doopl to read / write data with OPL from python:

from doopl.factory import *


# Create an OPL model from a .mod file
with create_opl_model(model="zootupleset.mod",data="zootupleset.dat") as opl:
    

    # Generate the problem and solve it.
    opl.run()

    # Get the names of post processing tables
    print("Table names are: "+ str(opl.output_table_names))

    # Get all the post processing tables as dataframes.
    for name, table in iteritems(opl.report):
        print("Table : " + name)
    for t in table.itertuples(index=False):
            print(t)

    # nicer display
    for t in table.itertuples(index=False):
        print(t[0]," buses ",t[1], "seats")
```

and then in the .dat you may use SheetRead to connect with an Excel spreadsheet.

See https://github.com/AlexFleischerParis/zooopl/blob/master/zooexcel.dat

SheetConnection s("zoo.xlsx");

```
params from SheetRead(s,"params!A2");
buses from SheetRead(s,"buses!A2:B3");
results to SheetWrite(s,"buses!E2:F3");
```

Comment: I did this and now the code is running. It even works on nested files, each linked to another .dat file. Thanks, @Alex Fleischer.